# Why Azure Devops don't recognize last test when we set build.updatebuildnumber

Tags: azure-devops

I saw that ever I set "build.updatebuildnumber" variable the test dashboard of build pipeline consider that all test are new.

```
 - script: 'echo ##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]v22.33.44-tst_namba'
    displayName: 'Update Build Number'
```

In this print screen, you can see 10 total tests but the azure devops consider that I added this 10 test in this build but this test I included many builds ago.
[image]

In This print screen you can see an example before setted "build.updatebuildnumber"
[image]

No matter if I add more test or just rerun the build pipeline, this dashboard ever show that I added all test as the last run was the first time that I runned that test. But this only happen when I change this variable: **build.updatebuildnumber**
[image]

Is this a Bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking.  Are you expecting to only run new tests that have been added incrementally in your new build?

Comment: Hi @Matt, I added more one picture to try to be more clear.

Comment: This issue is quite wired. Have you ever tried to update the build name to the next build name? For example, "20200826.4".

Comment: No, I define the build name with the tag name. I totally redefine this value to a value that has more sense for us.

Comment: @enamba I have tried many times, but I was unable to reproduce your issue. Could you please update the question to provide your YAML file? Be careful not to share personal data in the file.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue?